# Using VBA to create a zip file errors

Tags: vba

having some issues with using VBA to create a zip of a file. When I run the file I get the below error:

`Object variable or With block variable not set`.

Which is triggered when execution reaches this line:

`ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(folderToZipPath).items`.

I'm not very familiar with VBA but the MS docs suggested `Option Strict On` at the top of the file. When I add this however I just get another error:

`Expected: Base or Compare pr Explicit or Private`.

Any idea what is going on here?

```
Sub CreateZipFile(folderToZipPath As Variant, zippedFileFullName As Variant)

    Dim ShellApp As Object

    'Create an empty zip file
    Open zippedFileFullName For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1

    'Copy the files & folders into the zip file
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(folderToZipPath).items

    'Zipping the files may take a while, create loop to pause the macro until zipping has finished.
    On Error Resume Next
    Do Until ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).items.Count = ShellApp.Namespace(folderToZipPath).items.Count
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
Call CreateZipFile("C:\users\someuser\desktop\test", "C:\users\someuser\desktop\test.zip")
```

Comment: Alternatively, use my `Zip` function from [VBA.Compress](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Compress).

Comment: `Option Strict` is VB.net not VBA

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who has this issue. It turned out to be related to empty folders. If the folder below was empty, an exception was triggered.

```
ShellApp.Namespace(folderToZipPath).items
```